# building an interactive network(click-expand-click-collapse) in html using d3

Tags: html, d3.js, graph

I want to build a collapsible nodes view in html. I refered this website http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288#index.html

I saved the code as index.html in my wamp-server www folder. Then I tried opening this page but the page is totally blank. Any clue as to what could be the reason for non-rendering of the page on local machine ? How to fix this issue

Comment: did you create a readme.json file in same directory?

Comment: it looks like you didn't. your index.html does not contain any html, your html will be generated from your json file with d3.js, so if you did not include your file no wonder to get a blank as a result--> please refer to this documentationn https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1062288

Comment: Yeah that helped. Do you know an easier way to generate such -web based interactive expandible colapsible network ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same location (i.e. www folder) copy paste the readme.json file and it will work.